# Multiple case statements and search results in Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, case, rails-activerecord

I have a Calls model where I'm doing some reporting using the Reports Controller.

I can search by many different criteria and the results chain together properly to give me the expected search results.  I added a new one today to search by params :vehicle_type

```
results = case search[:vehicle_type]
              when "Ambulance"
                ambulance
              when "Wheelchair"
                wheelchair
              else
                scoped
              end
```

Ever since I added this case statement to the report method, the other case statement for :type (see below) does not work.  All other search criteria seem to work fine besides this one.

Am I doing something wrong here?  Can I not have more than one case statement in my report method to chain the results together?

```
 results = case search[:type]
              when "open"
                open_status
              when "canceled"
                cancel
              when "closed"
                closed
              when "waitreturn"
                waitreturn
              when "wheelchair"
                wheelchair
              else
                scoped
              end
```

Call.rb

```
class Call < ActiveRecord::Base 
  before_create :generate_incident_id, :set_dispatched_time
  attr_accessible :caller_address, :caller_street, :caller_state, :caller_zip, :caller_name, :caller_phone, :primary_diagnosis, :unit_assigned,
    :call_status, :incident_number, :facility_from, :facility_to, :unit_id, :nature_id, :facility_id, :caller_email, :facility_from_location,
    :facility_to_location, :patient_name, :patient_age, :patient_sex, :patient_insurance, :transfer_from_id, :transfer_to_id, :transfer_date,
    :dispatched_time, :en_route_time, :on_scene_time, :to_hospital_time, :at_hospital_time, :in_service_time, :service_level_id,
    :special_equipment_ids, :insurance_id, :transfer_from_other, :transfer_to_other, :unit_ids, :patient_sex_id, :incharge_id, :attendant_id,
    :incharge2_id, :attendant2_id, :wait_return, :cancel_reason_id, :parent_call_id, :imx_num, :dispatched_by, :traffic_type

  attr_writer :current_setup
  validates :caller_name, :caller_phone, :patient_name, :patient_age, :nature_id, :insurance_id, :presence => true
  has_many :call_units
  has_many :units, through: :call_units
  belongs_to :nature
  belongs_to :service_level
  belongs_to :patient_sex
  belongs_to :insurance
  has_many :call_special_equipments
  has_many :special_equipments, :through => :call_special_equipments
  belongs_to :transferred_from, :foreign_key => :transfer_from_id, :class_name => 'Facility'
  belongs_to :transferred_to, :foreign_key => :transfer_to_id, :class_name => 'Facility'
  belongs_to :parent_call, class_name: "Call"
  has_many :notes
  belongs_to :cancel_reason

  scope :open_status, where(call_status: "open")
  scope :cancel, where(call_status: "cancel")
  scope :closed, where(call_status: "close")
  scope :waitreturn, where(wait_return: "yes")
  scope :wheelchair, lambda { where(service_level_id: ServiceLevel.find_by_level_of_service("WC").id) }
  scope :bls, lambda { where(service_level_id: ServiceLevel.find_by_level_of_service("BLS").id) }
  scope :als, lambda { where(service_level_id: ServiceLevel.find_by_level_of_service("ALS").id) }
  scope :micu, lambda { where(service_level_id: ServiceLevel.find_by_level_of_service("MICU").id) }
  scope :cct, lambda { where(service_level_id: ServiceLevel.find_by_level_of_service("CCT").id) }
  scope :by_service_level, lambda { |service_level| where(service_level_id: ServiceLevel.find_by_level_of_service(service_level).id) }
  scope :from_facility, lambda { |id| where(transfer_from_id: id) }
  scope :to_facility, lambda { |id| where(transfer_to_id: id) }
  scope :search_between, lambda { |start_date, end_date| where("transfer_date BETWEEN ? AND ?", start_date.beginning_of_day, end_date.end_of_day)}
  scope :search_by_start_date,  lambda { |start_date| where('transfer_date BETWEEN ? AND ?', start_date.beginning_of_day, start_date.end_of_day) }
  scope :search_by_end_date, lambda { |end_date| where('transfer_date BETWEEN ? AND ?', end_date.beginning_of_day, end_date.end_of_day) }
  scope :open_calls, lambda { open_status.includes(:call_units).where(["call_units.unit_id IS NOT NULL"]) }
  scope :unassigned_calls, lambda { open_status.includes(:call_units).where(["call_units.unit_id IS NULL"]).order("calls.id ASC") }
  scope :assigned_calls, lambda { open_status.includes(:call_units).where(["call_units.unit_id IS NOT NULL"]).order("calls.id ASC") }
  scope :by_unit_name, lambda {|unit_name| joins(:units).where('units.unit_name = ?', unit_name)}
  scope :ambulance, lambda {joins(:units).where('units.vehicle_type = ?', "Ambulance")}
  scope :wheelchair, lambda {joins(:units).where('units.vehicle_type = ?', "Wheelchair")}


  #Scope to find scheduled calls
  scope :scheduled_calls, lambda { open_status.includes(:call_units).where(["calls.transfer_date > ?", Time.zone.now.end_of_day]) }

  # Scope to define all open calls scheduled and current assigned to medic in MDT view
  scope :medic_calls, lambda { where(["call_status = ? and call_units.unit_id IS NOT NULL", "open"]).order("id ASC") }

  # Scope to define all open calls scheduled and current for MDT view
  scope :today, lambda { where("transfer_date BETWEEN ? AND ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day, Time.zone.now.end_of_day) }
  scope :year, lambda { where("transfer_date BETWEEN ? AND ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_year, Time.zone.now.end_of_year) }
  scope :until_end_of_day, lambda { where("transfer_date < ?", Time.zone.now.end_of_day) }

  def self.search(search)

    if search
      where('incident_number LIKE ? OR patient_name ILIKE ?', "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%")
    else
      scoped
    end
  end

  #Report search logic
  def self.report(search)
    search ||= { type: "all" }

    # Determine which scope to search by
    results = case search[:type]
              when "open"
                open_status
              when "canceled"
                cancel
              when "closed"
                closed
              when "waitreturn"
                waitreturn
              when "wheelchair"
                wheelchair
              else
                scoped
              end

    results = case search[:vehicle_type]
              when "Ambulance"
                ambulance
              when "Wheelchair"
                wheelchair
              else
                scoped
              end

    results = results.by_unit_name(search[:unit_name]) if search[:unit_name].present?
    results = results.by_service_level(search[:service_level]) if search[:service_level].present?
    results = results.from_facility(search[:transferred_from]) if search[:transferred_from].present?
    results = results.to_facility(search[:transferred_to]) if search[:transferred_to].present?

    # If searching with BOTH a start and end date
    if search[:start_date].present? && search[:end_date].present?
      results = results.search_between(Date.parse(search[:start_date]), Date.parse(search[:end_date]))

      # If search with any other date parameters (including none)
    else
      results = results.search_by_start_date(Date.parse(search[:start_date])) if search[:start_date].present?
      results = results.search_by_end_date(Date.parse(search[:end_date])) if search[:end_date].present?
    end

    results
  end

  #Before create set dispatched time
  def set_dispatched_time
    self.dispatched_time = Time.zone.now
  end

  def dispatch!(unit_ids)
    units << Unit.find(unit_ids)
    set_dispatched_time
    save!
  end

  def closetime!
    self.closed_at = Time.zone.now
  end

  def elapsed_time
    (Time.zone.now - self.dispatched_time).to_i
  end

  def run_time
    (self.closed_at - self.dispatched_time).to_i
  end

  #Auto-increment incident_id
  def generate_incident_id
    incident_year = Time.now.year.to_s[2..-1]
    if Call.count == 0
      self.incident_number = "#{incident_year}-00001"
    else
      last_incident_number = Call.last.incident_number
      number = last_incident_number.split('-')[1].to_i
      number += 1
      self.incident_number = incident_year + '-' + "%05d" % number
    end
  end

  def overdue
    if transfer_date - Time.zone.now < 30.minutes
    end
  end

  def self.to_csv(records = [], options = {})
    CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
      csv << ["Incident Number", "Caller Name", "Caller Phone", "Call Created At", "Call Status", "Wait and Return", "Diagnosis", "Service Level", "Patient Name", "Patient Age", "Patient Sex", "Transfer From", "Transfer To", "Insurance", "Transfer Date", "Unit", "IMX Number"]
      records.each do |call|
        csv << [call.incident_number, call.caller_name, call.caller_phone, call.created_at, call.call_status, call.wait_return, call.nature.determinant, call.service_level.level_of_service, call.patient_name, call.patient_age, call.patient_sex.sex, transfer_from_name(call), transfer_to_name(call), call.insurance.insurance_type, call.transfer_date, call.units.map(&:unit_name).join(", "), call.imx_num]
      end
    end
  end

  def self.transfer_from_name(call)
    if call.transfer_from_id? 
      call.transferred_from.facility_name 
      else call.transfer_from_other 
    end
  end

  def self.transfer_to_name(call)
    if call.transfer_to_id? 
      call.transferred_to.facility_name 
      else call.transfer_to_other 
    end
  end

  def send_mail(mail_type)
    units.each do |unit|
      CallMailer.send(mail_type, unit.incharge,  self).deliver
      CallMailer.send(mail_type, unit.attendant, self).deliver
    end
  end
end
```

_search.html.erb

```
<div>
  <%= form_tag reports_path, :method => 'get' do %>  
    <p>
        <%= select_tag "search[type]", options_for_select([["All Statuses", "all"], ["Open", "open"], ["Closed", "closed"], ["Canceled", "canceled"], ["Wait & Return", "waitreturn"]], selected: params[:search].try(:[], :type)) %>
        <%= select_tag "search[service_level]", options_from_collection_for_select(ServiceLevel.order(:level_of_service), :level_of_service, :level_of_service, selected: params[:search].try(:[], :service_level)), prompt: "All Service Levels" %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= select_tag "search[vehicle_type]", options_for_select([["All Vehicles", "all"], ["Ambulance", "Ambulance"], ["Wheelchair", "Wheelchair"]], selected: params[:search].try(:[], :vehicle_type)) %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= text_field_tag "search[start_date]", params[:search].try(:[], :start_date), :placeholder => 'Start Date', :class => 'input-large search-query ', id: 'start_date_select' %>
        to 
        <%= text_field_tag "search[end_date]", params[:search].try(:[], :end_date), :placeholder => 'End Date', :class => 'input-large search-query', id: 'end_date_select'   %>
      </p>

      <p>
        Unit
        <%= select_tag "search[unit_name]", options_from_collection_for_select(Unit.order(:unit_name), :unit_name, :unit_name, selected: params[:search].try(:[], :unit_name)), prompt: "Any Unit" %>

      </p>

      <p>
        From
        <%= select_tag "search[transferred_from]", options_from_collection_for_select(Facility.order(:facility_name), :id, :facility_name, selected: params[:search].try(:[], :transferred_from)), prompt: "Any Facility" %>
        To
      <%= select_tag "search[transferred_to]", options_from_collection_for_select(Facility.order(:facility_name), :id, :facility_name, selected: params[:search].try(:[], :transferred_to)), prompt: "Any Facility" %>
      </p> 

      <p>
        Results Per Page
        <%= select_tag "per_page", options_for_select([["10", 10], ["25", 25] , ["50", 50], ["100", 100], ["All", 100000]], selected: params[:per_page]), class: "span1" %>
        <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil, :class => 'btn' %> <%= link_to "Export Search Results to CSV", reports_path(params.merge(format: "csv")), :class => "btn btn-info" %>

      </p>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

reports_controller.rb

```
 def index    
     @calls = Call.report(params[:search])
     respond_to do |format|
         format.html do
           @calls = @calls.paginate(:per_page => params[:per_page] || 10, :page => params[:page]).order('incident_number ASC')
         end
         format.csv { send_data Call.to_csv(@calls) }
         format.xls  { send_data @calls.to_csv(col_sep: "\t") }
       end
   end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second `case` statement is overwrite `results`. You probably want it to combine your existing scopes:

```
results = case search[:vehicle_type]
              when "Ambulance"
                results.ambulance
              when "Wheelchair"
                results.wheelchair
              else
                results.scoped
              end
```

Comment: Awesome, this seems to work.  Is it that the second case statement was a problem?  I've tested this and now I'm able to search by all criteria so far.  I didn't know that two case statements would be a problem.  The other results don't seem to get overwritten.  I'm confused as to why this would do it, but I am eager to learn.

Comment: You always need to apply scopes to the existing object (.e.g. `results = results.ambulance`) otherwise it will ignore any other scopes you already applied. The second statement was a problem because it "reset" the `results` object. Your other lines are in the format of `results = results.by_unit_name..` so they're not causing problems. But if they were just `results = by_unit_name` then only the very last `result = ` line would have any effect.

Comment: (Light bulb goes off).  I should have totally seen this.  Considering my other lines prepend results. i.e. results.by_unit_name.  I guess I was in a hurry when writing this second case statement I forgot that it would override the results object.  Thank you so much for the quick response and the 411!  You're awesome!